# Iterator or Enumeration, What should I use?

Tags: java, vector

I'm a newbie in java, 
I want to traverse the elements in a `Vector`. I'm getting the same result when I use **`Iterator`** / **`Enumeration`** interfaces.

As `Vector` is slow because it is synchronized. Does it enhance the performance in any aspect if I use **`Iterator`** / **`Enumeration`**.

Here's what I've tried

```
import java.util.*;

class vectorClass{
public static void main(String args[]){

    Vector<String> vector = new Vector<String>();
    vector.add("This is a vector Example\n");
    vector.add("This is a next line!");

    Enumeration en = vector.elements();
    while(en.hasMoreElements()){
        System.out.print(en.nextElement());
    }

    System.out.println();
    Iterator en1 = vector.iterator();
    while(en1.hasNext()){
        System.out.print(en1.next());
    }
}
}
```

O/P:

> This is a vector Example
>
> This is a next line!
>
> This is a vector Example
>
> This is a next line!

Comment: You shouldn't really use `Vector`, you should use `ArrayList`, where the question does not arise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no performance differences between `Enumeration` or `Iterator`. However, I would foster the use of `Iterator` since `Enumeration` is now deprecated (from the doc):

> NOTE: The functionality of this interface is duplicated by the
>   Iterator interface. In addition, Iterator adds an optional remove
>   operation, and has shorter method names. New implementations should
>   consider using Iterator in preference to Enumeration.

By the way, if you are not forced to use `Vector`, use `ArrayList` instead since `Vector` is slower because of constant synchronization but still not thread-safe. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1386288/4370629) for details.

From the javadoc, it is also recommended to use `ArrayList` instead of `Vector`:

> Unlike the new collection implementations, Vector is synchronized. If
>   a thread-safe implementation is not needed, it is recommended to use
>   ArrayList in place of Vector.